# wso2 api manager change super admin's password issue

Tags: passwords, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API Manager version 1.10.0.

i can't update API on Publisher portal after super admin password changed.
when I click "Next:Manage>" button, page has unlimited loading.

and publisher log print below.

ERROR APIProviderHostObject Login failed.Please recheck the username and password and try again..

after super admin password changed in carbon consol, i also change password property in user-mgt.xml (./repository/conf/user-mgt.xml)
but symptoms continue to appear.

How should I solve it?

Comment: Post the complete error log.

Comment: @Bhathiya just carbon.log print ERROR APIProviderHostObject Login failed.Please recheck the username and password and try again..

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of places where this password is used. `Grep` for `'admin'` inside `conf` directory to find them all.